# PDO SQLite query zero result issue

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I've had a look around but can't seem to find any information on this. I'm not sure if it's an issue with my code or a known issue with in-memory SQLite databases and PDO.

Basically, after inserting a single row into an in-memory SQLite database table, I'd expect that a query that doesn't match the inserted item to return zero rows. However, the following code gives a single row (false) but no actual PDO error code.

```
<?php

    // Create the DB
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Data we'll be using
    $name = 'Entry';

    // Create DB table
    $dbh->query('
        CREATE TABLE
            Test
            (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
            )
    ');

    // Insert data
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
        INSERT INTO
            Test
            (
                name
            )
        VALUES
            (
                :name
            )
    ');

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Check data has actually been inserted
    $entries = $dbh->query('
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            Test
    ')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($entries);

    // Query DB for non-existent items
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            Test
        WHERE
            name != :name
    ');

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    // How many rows returned
    echo $stmt->rowCount();

    // Actual data returned
    var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

I've managed to work-around the problem with some hackery but it'd be nice to not have to do this:

```
<?php

    echo (
        (0 == $stmt->rowCount()) || 
        (
            (1 == $stmt->rowCount()) && 
            (false === (($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)))) && 
            ('0000' == array_pop($dbh->errorInfo()))
        )
    ) ? 'true' : 'false';

?>
```

Can anyone help or point out any glaring mistakes that I may have made?

Comment: Just because you can write a complicated single expression doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Not sure which part of the code you're referring to Chris? What would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) returns

> ... the number of rows affected by the last **DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, *some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement*. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed** for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Welcome to PDO, where the easy stuff works and the not-so-easy stuff ruins your day.  SQLite is one of the drivers that doesn't have a reliable "how many rows are in my result set?" function.  From the comments:

> As of SQLite 3.x, the SQLite API itself changed and now all queries are implemented using "statements".  Because of this, there is no way for PDO to know the rowCount of a SELECT result because the SQLite API itself doesn't offer this ability.

A return of `false` from [PDOStatement::fetch()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) is a guarantee of "nothing came back," and your checking code is entirely sane, if a bit hard to read.  You may wish to consider wrapping or deriving from PDO and PDOStatement for your own sanity.

(Disclaimer: I am a PDO fanboy.)

Comment: Thanks Charles. I'm a huge fan of PDO too and have my own extended classes but this derived from isolated unit testing and I was trying to pull things back to be as simple as possible.